# Does health/radiation recover automatically?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Simply put, does the health of occupants recover automatically when not under attack etc, or does it only recover when you use a stimpak/radaway on them?

If it does recover, does it do so when the game is inactive?

I'm playing on PS4 if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are yes, they both recover assuming you have the food/water requirements.

However, they are both very, very slow...